# Is there a downfall for using a large grid (ie 48 col) with the susy grid framework?

Tags: css, grid, susy-compass

I'm using Susy as CSS grid framework and I find that 48 columns gives me alot more control over the design. Most of the time 24 or even 12 columns is more that enough, but for special cases 48 is a bit more convenient.

I've noticed that the web standard seems to be 12, with Bootstrap & Foundation for example. Concerning those I understand that a larger grid would generate alot more css. But since Susy doesn't have that problem, is there another reason for limiting your columns to 12? To me it seems there isn't, but since most people are using 12 columns I can't shake the feeling that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. That should work fine. Cheers!